# Limit a query with subitems

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a list of puzzles that can be solved with certain tools. Now I select my tools and I want to know which puzzle I can solve and with which tool on my list. Here is my sql (for mysql)

```
 SELECT p.name puzzle, countr.cnt, tool.id toolId,[etc]
 FROM
puzzles p
 INNER JOIN
tools_for_puzzle tfp
 ON tfp.id_puzzle = p.id 
 INNER JOIN
tools t
 ON t.id= tfp.id_tool
INNER JOIN
(
   select tfp2.id_puzzle, count(*) cnt from tools_for puzzle tfp2
   where tfp2.id_tool in (21,22,23,24,25,26,27) group by id_puzzle
) countr
 ON
countr.id_puzzle=tfp.id_puzzle
 WHERE
t.id IN (21,22,23,24,25,26,27)
    order by cnt desc   limit 50
```

As a Result I get something like
Puzzle1, Tool1, 2
Puzzle1, Tool2, 2
Puzzle2, Tool1, 1
Puzzle3, Tool3, 1

The counter is needed to know which puzzle I can solve easier because I have more tools. I'm not sure the query is optimized enough, though. What I get as result are 50 rows that doesn't represent 50 possible puzzles, but just the sum of the rows. Hypotetically I can get just one Puzzle if I use the IDs of 50 tools I need to do it.

How do I set my query in order to get 50 different puzzles instead of puzzle,tool? If I group by Puzzle, I will lose the id/name of the tools! Should I run a third query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you are looking for puzzles that match a given set of tools.  This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  A flexible way of solving this is using aggregation.

The following query will return, for each puzzle, the number of tools and the list of them (comma separated).  It is ordered by the most tools to the fewest, for puzzles that match your list:

```
SELECT p.name, p.puzzle, count(*) as numtools, group_concat(t.id) as tools
FROM puzzles p INNER JOIN
     tools_for_puzzle tfp
     ON tfp.id_puzzle = p.id INNER JOIN
     tools t
     ON t.id= tfp.id_tool
WHERE t.id IN (21,22,23,24,25,26,27)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY numtools desc;
```

Comment: I did not know group_concat! It solved my problem and made the query faster as well! Interesting is also that it seems there are other ways to do it. This seems to be the most elegant as long as I need just the tools to match. Thanks!

Comment: this might sound dumb, but is it possible to change it to a noSQL query? I am testing the query and it seems slow, so I'm wondering if changing the technology might change the speed.

Comment: @mobinoob . . . You should ask that as a separate question with the NoSQL tag.